# Main screen bleeding over onto second HDMI screen

Tags: screen

I have a laptop running Ubuntu connected by an HDMI cable to a large HD screen. Everything is working well, except that the main screen is partially showing on my second screen. It looks like the last two columns of pixels are bleeding over onto the peripheral screen and it's really bothering me.

I already tried playing with the aspect ratio but that hasn't rectified the problem.

Comment: Install [arandr](https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/), it will help you to work with your screen schema. So you can save this definition and execute it as necessary.

Comment: "I already tried playing with the aspect ratio but that hasn't rectified the problem"... The problem seems to be incorrect resolution, not scaling.